# Rails: using rake:notes for javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Is there a way to configure rake:notes to parse javascript files and emit respective notes?
Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You can do this with grep directly if you want

```
grep -r 'OPTIMIZE:\|FIXME:\|TODO:' public/javascripts
```

If you wanted only TODO's

```
grep -r 'TODO:' public/javascripts # Find on todos
```

You could use the following to Search all js in the project, not just the files under public javascripts.

```
grep -r 'OPTIMIZE:\|FIXME:\|TODO:' **/*.js
```

Here is how you can turn this into a rake task.

```
# File lib/tasks/notes.rake

namespace :notes do
  task :js do
    puts `grep -r 'OPTIMIZE:\\|FIXME:\\|TODO:' public/javascripts`
  end
end
```

Now you can execute `rake notes:js` from the project root.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4.2 you already have support for javascript annotations, altough if you want to add anotatoions for other extensions add this line to your `config/application.rb` file:

```
config.annotations.register_extensions("ext1", "ext2", "txt3") { |annotation| /\/\/\s*(#{annotation}):?\s*(.*)$/ }
```